solana program deploy error
An error message is reported when the following command is used to deploy the program on the devnet network:
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/study.so

Error message:
thread 'main' panicked at cli/src/program.rs:2809:26:
Should return a valid tpu client: PubsubError(ConnectionError(Io(Os { code: 60, kind: TimedOut, message: "Operation timed out" })))
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


Maybe there is something wrong with your RPC url.
You can see it using solana config get
You can try run it with:
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/study.so --url https://api.devnet.solana.com

You could also try the parameter --use-rpc

Please use this option.
--with-compute-unit-price 100000
--use-quic
